# Why does javah need the bytecode to generate JNI headers?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, javah

This is a question which puzzles me. `javah` needs a classpath, of bytecode-compiled classes, in order to generate its headers.

But there is `javac` which, presumably, builds an AST out of the source code, which could possibly be used by `javah` as well. Especially since native methods are easily spotted.

So, why does `javah` need the bytecode at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because that's how they wrote it. I agree, it absolutely *could* have been written to operate on source, but that's not what they did.

The somewhat interesting thing about the way it *is* written is that you can use it if you have source (by compiling it first) or if you *don't* have source; that means the way it's done is actually *more* flexible, not less.

Comment: That's true, but on the other hand it makes the JNI build process more complicated than it could be :/

Comment: @fge No it doesn't. You have one compiler, that compiles .java to .class; you have one javah, that processes .class to .c and .h. Making javah a compiler would introduce a risk of divergence between it and javac.

Comment: @EJP not if they share their code! But anyway... I know I have to deal with it :/